# separating php and html, stuck in loading images and css

Tags: php, html, templates, web, directory

I'm new with php. I have a question about separating php and html. This is the root directory of my website

```
Root
  template 
      html
         image  
         script
         css
         main.html
   main.php
  template.php
```

when I load the main.php by using template.php and main.html, images are not displayed. I know the reason is wrong directory(the current directory is root, not template/html). So how can I fix this problem? How can I import to main.php?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache and can use `.htaccess` to add rewrite rules, you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule image/(.*) template/html/image/$1
RewriteRule script/(.*) template/html/script/$1
RewriteRule css/(.*) template/html/css/$1
```

Or another solution is to add `template/html/` prefix to all image/script/css URLs manually.

Answer (score -2):

When you include a PHP file from a HTML file you need to use the script tag. In your case you need to do something like as follows:

```
<script src="template/main.php"></script>
```

and when you import a PHP file from another PHP file you need to use the include thing.

Comment: This is incorrect. Unless you are dynamically generating JavaScript (which doesn't appear to be the case here), using `<script>` is not related to including PHP at all. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/html (or google "learn html").